# Is there an official way to support failover in grpc-java?

Tags: java, spring, grpc-java

When using [grpc-java](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java), is there a recommended way to support failover?

For instance, you are connected to one server, which then goes down. What is the recommended way do you recover from that?

I have seen the experimental `LoadBalancer` class. Is it intended to solve the problem? There are also various Interceptor classes, but I am not sure how to use them to react on connection errors.

We are using the [grpc-spring-boot-starter](https://github.com/LogNet/grpc-spring-boot-starter), but I do not see failover support, there, either.

What I would like to avoid is handling all reconnects in the business classes. For instance, by catching exceptions there and building up a connection to the next available server. If possible that should be handled transparently.

Answer (score 0):

It is not an official dependency

https://github.com/yidongnan/grpc-spring-boot-starter

In client

```
@GrpcClient("gRPC server name")
private Channel serverChannel;

GreeterGrpc.GreeterBlockingStub stub = GreeterGrpc.newBlockingStub(serverChannel);
HelloReply response = stub.sayHello(HelloRequest.newBuilder().setName(name).build());
```

The client request will use load balancing.

Comment: How does it know where to load balance to?